# Problem with if elsif else Bash Script. Can somebody help me?

Tags: bash, if-statement

Hi i am having a problem with my piece of code. for some reason it is not working. here is my script:

```
 if [ $(cat utxobalance.txt) -eq 4100000 ]&&[ $(find metadata3/ | wc -l) -ge 1 ]; >>logginng.txt
    then
        ###1 NFT version 1###
        echo $in_addr >| addr1.txt
        echo $tx_in >| multitx1.txt
        sh ./version1.sh >>logginng.txt 
    elif [ $(cat utxobalance.txt) -eq 4200000 ]&&[ $(find metadata3-1/ | wc -l) -ge 1 ]; >>logginng.txt
        then
        ###1 NFT version 2###
        echo $in_addr >| addr2.txt
        echo $tx_in >| multitx2.txt
        sh ./version2.sh 
    elif [ $(cat utxobalance.txt) -eq 4500000 ]&&[ $(find metadata3/ | wc -l) -ge 1 ] && [ $(find metadata3-1/ | wc -l) -ge 1 ]; then
        
        echo $in_addr >| addr3.txt
        echo $tx_in >| multitx3.txt
        sh ./version3.sh >>logginng.txt
        else >>logginng.txt
        echo ${utxo_balance} >> $log
        echo "Refund Initiated..." >> $log
```

If i put in the utxobalance.txt 4100000 it goes to the right script (version1.sh) but if i put in 4200000 in the utxobalance.txt it also goes to the script version1.sh ( it should go to version2.sh). Also if i put in 4500000 in utxobalance.txt it goes to version1.sh Where it has to go to version3.sh.

can somebody tell me what is wrong ?

Comment: You can't end on an `elif`.

Comment: no sorry my code is not complete ill update it now

Comment: Please make it a [mre].

Comment: There are lots of problems here. Try running it through http://shellcheck.net first.

Comment: utxobalance.txt is mentioned without a path: are you 100% sure you're in the right directory when you edit that file?

Answer (score 0):

In your `if` statement, **the conditional is actually a (semicolon-separated) list** of these two commands:

```
  [ $(cat utxobalance.txt) -eq 4100000 ]&&[ $(find metadata3/ | wc -l) -ge 1 ]
```

and

```
  >>logginng.txt
```

The status of a list of statements (or rather a list of "pipelines" in bash terminology) is always the status of its last entry. In your case, it's an output redirection statement, which will always be successful -- therefore, the first `if` clause will always match.

A minimal reproducible example for this would be the following:

```
$ if false ; >output.txt ; then echo foo ; fi
foo
```